# segue from second view controller to first view controller ios8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, segue, unwind-segue

I have 4 ViewControllers. Three of those view controllers are connected to the fourth one, which I call Photo_Detail. The segues there work fine, but now I have to make the back button go to the VC that someone came from. How can I do that? A research said to create a unwind segue in the Photo_detail, what i did but it didn't work out. That's the code I tried to use:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Popping back to this view controller!");
    // reset UI elements etc here
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Are you using navigation controller? How did one came to secondviewcontroller?

Comment: No. There just are 3 VC's that have a button each, that say's show detail. When one of them is pressed, the `prepareForSegue` method takes them over and adjusts the info

Comment: Yes but in storyboard, which type is used push, modal or custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Popping back to this view controller!");
    // reset UI elements etc here
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

For Modal type segues, this will help you to move back.

And also select it as normal action from `ViewController` rather then `exit`. That will fix it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey. Unfortunately that doesn't work. I connect it as exit and nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there NSLog getting printed in console?

Comment: Okay. I found out what needs to be done. It has to be connected as normal action not exit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the second VC is presented modally, you simply have to dismiss the controller

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]:
```